# Using _this to refer to parent class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, this

I'm using the prefix _this to refer to a parent class function when calling it from a callback function. However, when I run the node server I get the error message '_this is not defined'. I've actually pulled this code directly from a MEAN stack book I'm learning from but I can't seem to get around this.

Parent Function

```
var getErrorMessage = function(err){
var message = '';
if(err.code){
    switch(err.code){
        case 11000:
        case 11001:
        message = 'Username already exists';
        break;
        default:
        message = 'Something went Wrong';
    }
} else{
    for(var errName in err.errors){
        if(err.errors[errName].message){
            message = err.errors[errName].message;
        }
    }
}

return message;
};
```

Function being called in a callback later on

```
exports.saveOAuthUserProfile = function(req, profile, done){
User.findOne({provider: profile.provider, providerId: profile.providerId}, function(err,user){
    if(err){
        return done(err);
    } else{
        if(!user){
            var possibleUsername = profile.username || ((profile.email) ? profile.email.split('@')[0] : '');

            User.findUniqueUsername(possibleUsername, null, function(availableUsername){
                profile.username = availableUsername;

                user = new User(profile);

                user.save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        var message = _this.getErrorMessage(err);
                        req.flash('error',message);

                        return res.redirect('/signup');
                    } else{
                        return done(err,user);
                    }
                });
            });
        } else{
            return done(err, user);
        }
    }
});
};
```

Comment: where is `_this` variable declared like `var _this = something`

Comment: I don't have it declared anywhere which is what was confusing. These lines of code are taken directly from the book. It may help noting that he has var message = \_this.getErrorMessage... on two seperate lines, where line 2 starts with _this.get.... I've tried taking the "\_" off the beginning but then I get the message that ".getErrorMessage()" does not exist.

Comment: Well in that case `_this` has to be defined, its not a reserved keyword or any of that sorts but `this` is a reserved keyword. I would suggest you to remove `_this` and directly call the method you intend to call. If you still want `_this` then declare `var _this = {}; _this.getErrorMessage  = getErrorMessage `. It should work with breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuation with the comment

**Declare as below after the parent function in global scope.**

```
var _this = {};
_this.getErrorMessage = getErrorMessage; // Passing the function reference
```

**Later in callback**

```
_this.getErrorMessage(/*YOUR_PARAMETERS_HERE*/);
```

---

Alternatively you can remove `_this` completely and call the function directly as the parent function is in global scope.

**Note:** the understanding is Both the parent function and callback is in the same `.js` file with parent function declared on global scope with respect to that `.js`file and not declared as `GLOBAL.getErrorMessage` which makes it explicitly global as `window` object in client side.

Comment: using just getErrorMessage() worked. Must be a typo in the book.